# Adding Django M2M Relationship between two 3rd Party Models

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I need to create a Many-to-Many relationship between two models.  In Django, you'd normally add a `ManyToManyField` to one of the the two models.  In my case, however:

- The two models are from 3rd party libraries, trivially `User` and `Car`
- Both are non-abstract and I want to avoid, for example, the complexity of multi-table inheritance just to add a M2M field (which does not actually require extra columns in either table)
- I'm working on the assumption that others will use this like (if not literally as) a 3rd party library so I *really* want to provide standard interfaces despite the constraints.

Obviously, I can create a "manual" M2M table:

```
class UserCar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'car')
```

... but Django would treat both `ForeignKey` fields as Many-to-One so the standard "magic" accessors won't be available:

```
user.cars.add(car)
car in user.cars
User.objects.filter(cars=car)
```

Is there an easy way to inject the usual M2M magic on both sides of the relationship?  `UserCar` is basically a `through=` table.  Can I create a dummy field and call a method or two (e.g. `contribute_to_class` and `contribute_to_related_class`) to get this done?  I tried puzzling through `ForeignKey` and `ManyToMany`, but I'm not familiar enough with normal Field-level processing to even guess at the critical methods (let alone sequencing and delayed processing).

Comment: You can try to use `User.add_to_class('cars', 
 models.ManyToManyField(....))` but I am uncertain on this. It can complain about migrations and if this is third party package I am not sure what next. Maybe it will create new migration to that package). Anyway,  give it a chance. P. S.  it will also call contribute_to_class that you've mentioned.

Comment: I'll definitely give this a try.  The "through" model should get created either way... either it's picked up as the through model or it's not and it's just a first-class citizen that's created on its own.

Comment: Yes,  I do understand.  However,  when you add ManyToManyField even with through table,  django will still create a migration to track that field in migration history,  even if this doesn't change anything in database.  I am not sure now,  but there is a big chance)

Comment: I used a simple `if not hasattr` as a guard against repeated calls to `add_to_class`.  It adds the field, but the migration is created in the same package as `Car` (I added the field to `Car`) so they won't get committed to my repo.

Comment: Hmm.  Is it okay to create migration inside third party?  Maybe they're is a way to add only RelatedManager? Maybe you should take a look at ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class...

Comment: I am wondering why you are trying to solve this problem.  There is a package that allows for easier handling of multiple databases within Django, but the details of dealing with that are left to the developer.  See https://github.com/avelino/django-routers.  In other words, I don't think you should have to worry about a model to an external database if you're just making a simple package for developers to incorporate into their projects.  Django rightfully abstracts all those details away.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear.  I'm not suggesting a new database.  I need to add a M2M relationship between existing models.  Normally, you'd add a `ManyToManyField` to one of them.  Since the models are in 3rd party packages, I can't simply add the field.  So I need to create the M2M table in my own package and "inform" the two pre-existing models that the relationship is M2M not simply a Many-To-One `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, @AlexandrTatarinov suggests using `add_to_class` to add a `ManyToManyField` to `Car` right after creating the `through` table.  I'm still open to better answers, but it's certainly an answer (and currently the best available).  Assume we use code like:

```
# guard against repeated import
if not hasattr(Car, 'users'):
    field = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=UserCar, related_name='cars')
    field.contribute_to_class(Car, 'users')
```

The effect (including drawbacks) of this approach are:

- Magic accessors are added to both sides of the relationship
- A migration (adding the M2M field) is placed in the app for `Car`.  This migration **will not be committed to the repository for my package** and could lead to some odd issues.  For example,

  - If a developer uses my package as a dependency, the migration will be (re)created when the developer calls `makemigrations`.  If the `Car` package is later upgraded (and includes new migrations), this could result in an error like "two leaf nodes" on the development machine.
- When I delete the `Car` migration to simulate a production scenario case, a trivial test *does* work (e.g. after creating two objects in relation, `user.places` and `place.users` works correctly)
- Because the M2M table is defined as a `through` table, methods like `place.users.add()` don't work out of the box (even though the M2M table is exactly the same as one auto-created by the field).

The issue with `place.users.add()` is raised because `auto_created=False` on a manually created `through=` model.  If I set `auto_created=Car` in `UserCar.Meta`, the magic methods work but migrations aren't created.  To take advantage of the default migrations *and* restore through behaviors, I was able to use the following:

```
@receiver(request_started)
def set_auto_created(**kwargs):
    UserCar._meta.auto_created = Car
```

EDIT: In an earlier iteration, I was using `auto_created=True`.  This was causing an issue with `FLUSH` in a `TransactionTestCase`.  After digging through the M2MField code, it looks like `auto_created` needs to be pointed at the model holding the `ManyToManyField`.  I think it has something to do with how auto-created tables are managed in a `TransactionTestCase`.

EDIT2: I also tried to attach the signal to `post_migrate`.  This works fine for tests (since they always migrate) but didn't work in production.  `request_started` appears to work for both.

With this enhancement, the extra migration created in the app for `Car` is the only major issue with this strategy.